# Google Maps not displaying when using the sample

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I have loaded up the SimpleMapDemo from the Google Play Services sample. I have retrieved a Google API Key, yet the map does not display when deploying the app to the emulator. There is no internal errors yet the map is not displaying.

I have generated a logcat output file to try and find the problem, yet I am not sure what to exactly look for.

May I please have some help to figure out what is wrong? Here is the logcat output file: http://canninginc.co.nz/logcat/logfile.txt

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you Google Play Services installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you need a debug key certificate to get your api key, i mean, you dont have to use your real key certificate.

- make sure your JRE folder is in your PATH
- open CMS and go to  C:\Users[USER NAME].android
- run `keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore  -storepass android -keypass android`
- copy the `Certificate fingerprint SHA1`

go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and create your api key with this fingerprint

---

Also, check out the version of your emulator.  Remember that Play services only work on SDK version 4.2.2 or higher.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services.

also, there are some tricks around to make it work in previous versions, i guess you already tried since [google gives a lot of useful results](https://www.google.es/search?q=google%20map%20android%20emulator&rlz=1C1ASUT_enES519ES519&oq=google%20map%20android%20emulat&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7458j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I do not have a debug.keystore file in my [users]\[my name]\.android folder. I have used the [users]\[my name]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\ folder instead. Is this the correct debug.keystore file to use?

Comment: It is good if that is the one your ide is using to sign the apk. Im eclipse you can check it here: Windows > Preferences > Android > Build. If you are not using eclipse you have to find out. Also, you can learn more about signing in debug mode here (http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode)

Comment: Do you recommend I use Eclipse? I am currently using Xamarin.

Comment: I always recommend eclipse since is the most widely used, and thats good for since its easier to find help from the community.  But if you like xamarin,and it is working for you, thats enough. About this particular error, I cannot say that migrating to eclipse will fix it. Actually an emulator can run any apk, so it just that you check that the debug keystore you are using to get the api key is the same that xamatin uses to sign the apk, wnd also that the emulator uses the correct version of android, and has play services installed

Answer (score 0):

create your new google maps API Key and replace this key in AndroidManifest